# Excluding a Portion of a Monitor from the Desktop

Tags: debian, x11, display, xrandr

My monitor supports configurable pictute-in-picture. I like to keep my Linux desktop connected to the main mDP input, with a second machine connected via HDMI shown as PIP in the bottom-right corner. This usually works fine, but sometimes windows and other content gets "lost" behind the PIP window. Is it possible to somehow "exclude" a rectangular region from the desktop such that e.g. the mouse cursor acts as if it's a barrier, and windows don't end up entirely within the region?

Comment: which Desktop Environment ?

Comment: @RoVo Cinnamon. I assumed this would be at a lower layer though.

Comment: After some exploration, it seems this functionality would be the responsibility of the [window manager](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/window_manager). Cinnamon's window manager, Muffin, does not support it. Others might, but Cinnamon doesn't appear to play nicely with anything other than Muffin, and I don't really want to change my desktop environment.